# format string in printf

Tags: c, casting

What is the output?

```
main()
{
    float a=4;
    int i=2;
    printf("%f %d",i/a,i/a);
    printf("%d %f",i/a,i/a);
}
```

The answer I'm receiving is: `0.500000 00 0.000000`

Reason: In the first `printf`,  `%f=i/a=2/4=int/float` so the implicit casting is done and `i` becomes `float` which causes a result of a `float` (i.e 0.500000).

Default precision of float is 6 so after decimal 6 digit then next `%d=i/a=2 /4=0.500000`, but `%d` format string print only integer so 0 is printed and after decimal values are discarded.

Next `printf` with `%d=i/a=2/4` print 0 has the same concept; however, `%f=i/a=2/4=0.000000` last result I did not understand.

Comment: Why not try? [Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) You can try out all sorts of stuff, even when not in front of a PC loaded with all stuff needed for it...

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what it is that you don't understand?

Comment: "implicit casting" is an oxymoron. Casting is explicit by definition. The word you are looking for is "implicit conversion".

Comment: Also use ` to mark inline code, so that what you write becomes nicer to our eyes

Comment: I only see 3 outputs but 4 format arguments to `printf`.

Comment: And also question `is did not understand`...

Comment: Printing a float using `%d` is undefined behavior. My compiler settings warn against this.

Answer (score 4):

This plain [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to specify the wrong format specifier to `printf` in both cases the `i/a` expression will be promoted to `double` and you are specifying that it is a `int` for one argument. The [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* which `printf`'s section refers back to for the format string paragraph *9* says:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.[...]

You should enable warning but both `gcc` and `clang` will warn about this without cranking them up at all, in `gcc` I obtain the following message:

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat]
```

Comment: are you sure? Will the `int` not get promoted to a `float`?

Comment: @Bathsheba You are right that `i/a` is `float`, but in a variable argument function like `printf`, `float` is promoted to `double`.

Answer (score 3):

`i/a` expression will always evaluate to `float` since one of the operands are `float`. While printing, we are using specifiers `%d` and `%f`. So when we use `%f` it will (should) always be 0.5 and when we use `%d` it should be `undefined`.

On Linux (ubuntu) with gcc compiler I get following output (added a `\n` after first print for clarity):

```
0.500000 2047229448
899608576 0.500000
```

Answer (score 2):

*Undefined behaviour*: all the data types in `printf` are implicitly floats. This is because `i/a` has type `float` as the `int` datum gets promoted to floating point. So you must use `%f` exclusively in your `printf`.